# How to change the spreadsheet order in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a survey in Sharepoint 2010. Now i added a new question . Then I went to `survey settings` to make sure that this question is `order 1` . However when i export the survey to excel spreadsheet , this question is the in the last column ?

in the survey itself ,  the new question appears the first , order 1(BTW there is no branching ) .

However when i export it to spreadsheet it it the last . How can make this question to be the first in the spreadsheet either ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Export to Excel function simply takes the SharePoint list data without any views applied.  So that means it takes the columns in the order they were created.

You could delete the columns and recreate them with the first column being created first, then the second and so on.  But if there is a lot of data you want to keep in those columns you could keep it and simply create another list then find a way to copy the items over to the new list.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "export to spreadsheet" function in SharePoint surveys use the "Overview" (view) by default.

1. Go into SharePoint Designer and select your survey list
2. Under the "View" section (on the right) select "Overview". It should be the 
   default
3. Double-click overview to open / edit it
4. Look for the "Viewfields" section. Under it all your survey fields will be 
   listed with the first listed column to be exported (Excel A1) followed by 
   the rest (note that your column names many be truncated)
5. Cut the columns you want to move and paste them where you want them
6. Click save before exiting

When you perform your next export, the columns should be in the order you desire